# Do Apache2 VirtualHost <Directory> directives cascade?

Tags: .htaccess, http, server, virtualhost, apache2.4

I feel like this question must have been asked before, but I could not find anything.

If I have a simple VirtualHost with two separate `<Directory>` directives:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory /var/www>
        Require all granted
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/api> # does the order matter?
        Require local
        Options -Indexes # is this redundant?
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

My questions are:

- Does the order of the  directives matter? What would happen if the `/var/www/api` directive came first?
- Is the second `Options -Indexes` redundant?
- Do the settings cascade because `/var/www/api` is a subdirectory of `/var/www`?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out? A question of a few minutes you invest.

Comment: Did you at least read the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)? `If multiple (non-regular expression) <Directory> sections match the directory (or one of its parents) containing a document, then the directives are applied in the order of shortest match first, interspersed with the directives from the .htaccess files. For example…`. [Another explanation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See official documentation on [section merging](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) and the [Directory directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) (thanks @emix)

- Yes, the second `Options -Indexes` is redundant because the `Options -Indexes` setting for `/var/www` is inherited.

  - The inherited setting can be overridden e.g. `Options +Indexes` rule for `/var/www/api` will show indexes.
- The order of the directives does not seem to matter. The rules seem to cascade by directory structure, not the order of the directives themselves.
- Yes, the settings for `/var/www` cascade because `/var/www/api` is a subdirectory.